# Finding transformation matrix given the image vector and pre-image vector

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For $$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\ b&a\end{bmatrix}$$
find $a$ and $b$ such that $T(12,5) = (13,0)$.

I can't figure out how to set this problem up to solve it. I've tried row reducing an augmented matrix after I made a system of linear equations but that didn't work.

*Update*

I used the system of equations

**a - b = 12**

**a + b = 5**

and then row reduced the augmented matrix of that system. When I plugged those solutions into the original transformation matrix *A* and multiplied it by (12,5), it didn't give me the (13,0) result.

Comment: Can you express $T(12,5)$ as a function of $a,b$?

Comment: I'm assuming  $A$ means the corresponding matrix to the linear map $T$. Try computing $Ax$ with $x = (12,5)$. What do you get?

Comment: "I've tried row reducing an augmented matrix after I made a system of linear equations but that didn't work." What system of equations did you get, what did you get after row reduction, and why doesn't it "work"?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: What is $T(12,5)$? Can you write down a formula for it, in terms of $a$ and $b$?

Hint 2: Now set 
$$T(12,5) = \left[\begin{array}{c}13\\0\end{array}\right].$$
This is a pair of equations with two unknowns. Can you solve it?